# Array of string to be used in an expression for vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visio

First of all, I might have framed the title incorrectly as I am not sure about it.

I am trying to create a formula for "Polyline" in Visio using VB.NET.

I am doing all the steps correctly (that's what i think) except putting the array of string together.

Here is the code:

```
Dim xPoly As New List(Of String)()

For lRow1 = 2 To 194
   xPoly.Add(((xlsheet.Cells(lRow1, 8).value - iX) * 12) - xPS.Cells("PinX").ResultIU + iOX)
   xPoly.Add(((xlsheet.Cells(lRow1, 9).value - iY) * 12) - xPS.Cells("PinY").ResultIU + iOY)

Next lRow1

   Dim sFormula As String = "Polyline(" & xPoly.ToString & ")"

   xPS.AddRow(Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionFirstComponent, 2, Visio.VisRowTags.visTagPolylineTo)
   xPS.CellsSRC(Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionFirstComponent, 2, 3).FormulaU = Chr(34) & "POLYLINE(" & xPoly.ToString & ")" & Chr(34)
```

This brings a list of X and Y coordinates from an excel file. I want these coordinates to be in one line, like: `(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3,......)`. Then use this, as a string, in the "Polyline" function of visio, so it becomes, `"Polyline(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3........)"`.

I am not able to do the last step. There is something wrong in my code, but I am not able to figure out what. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `xPoly.ToString`, perhaps what you mean is `String.Join(", ", xPoly)`.

Comment: @Blackwood it worked. Can you please post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created a `List(Of String)` containing the coordinates and you want to convert it to a single string with the elements separated by commas, use the `String.Join` method.

```
Dim sFormula As String = "Polyline(" & String.Join(", ", xPoly) & ")"
```